# XNA Content Build Output not refreshed until all content is built

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Is there a way to see realtime logs about content being built using the XNA Content Pipeline ?

Some content take a long time to process with many steps and it would be great to get feedback about what is going on as an asset is being processed.
I tried ContentProcessorContext.Logger, Console.WriteLine, Debug.WriteLine and also tried to increase MSBuild verbosity (all levels) without success; the logs are displayed to the Visual Studio Output Window only when all content has been built.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I just did a quick google and this might be of interest to you http://badcorporatelogo.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/faster-content-builds-that-dont-lock-up-your-ide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me - context.Logger.LogImportantMessage(...);

but for anything complex you will need to debug the build... this is one way....

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/11/08/debugging-the-content-pipeline.aspx

The way I prefer (actually I prefer not to have to debug the content pipeline), but when I must:

1. I open up a new instance of visual studio open up the file in whichI  wish to place a breakpoint
2. place the break point
3. attach this instance of VS to the other (proper) instance of VS

When I then compile/build the breakpoint will be hit

Hope this helps.